# How to install packages into a non-writable directory

Tags: r

[image: ERROR]

[image: CONSOLE]

the similar error occurs every time for packages like dplyr,data.table.

Comment: It appears your library folder is not writeable. Does it work when you run as administrator? You could also set your `lib.path` to a different location. My solution had always been to install R somewhere *not* program files, e.g. `C:\R`.  That way R is guaranteed to have write access to it's default library location.

Comment: It seems that for some reason you don't have permissions to write to that directory (that is unexpected). Looking around, it seems that there are a couple of things that you could try, including changing the folder where you keep the libraries ([FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#I-don_0027t-have-permission-to-write-to-the-R_002d3_002e6_002e0_005clibrary-directory), [link2](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-after-r-update-lib-c-program-files-r-r-3-5-0-library-is-not-writable/7947/3))

Comment: I wouldn't recommend resorting to installing packages as an administrator. Check your `.libPaths()`, then use something like `.Rprofile` to set it correctly if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to make the default folder writeable (often we don't want that, depending on where it is), then choose a great spot on your computer where you want the libraries you install and then place this in your `.Rprofile` file (often in your My Documents folder

```
.libPaths("full path to your personal library folder")
```

This will not overwrite the default `.libPaths`; it will just append your personal folder to the folders that R knows about already (so it can still find the system installed libraries)

Comment: I just tried to change location but it is not helping. Is their any specific thing that should be kept in mind while setting a new location , or simply where do i change location to?

Comment: The folder you put in that command must exist; did you make it first?

Comment: Yes I created a new folder. But the location of libraries didn't change and is giving same error with the old location mentioned in it again, even after I used the command that you advised above.